# Paste append pasting blank cells

Tags: ms-access

I am new to Microsoft Access but not databases.

I am attempting to use Access as a data model in multiple Excel spreadsheets.

I already have some hardcoded data records in my spreadsheets, and I want to port them over to the Access table.

So I basically have the data I want to copy and paste over as a multiline (\r) text file copied to the clipboard. The data looks like this:

```
Stable
Interactive Media & Services
Wireless Telecommunication Services
Internet & Direct Marketing Retail
Specialty Retail
Household Products
Personal Products
Oil, Gas & Consumable Fuels
Banks
Capital Markets
Consumer Finance
Health Care Providers & Services
Biotechnology
Aerospace & Defense
Air Freight & Logistics
IT Services
Software
REIT
Electric Utilities
Independent Power and Renewable Electricity
```

I have the table open, and on the (New) line, I click Paste Append. This adds the 20 records but the Title field is left blank...

[image]

I've checked and the data types for the cell are text. I'm not sure how to resolve this.

Comment: before pasting, only select the title column, not the whole row.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the Title field, not the row. Left click on the column header then Ctrl+V or right click Paste.

If you want to paste into table that already has records, then highlight blank 'cell' under Title column. This is a little tricky. Point cursor at cell edge until it changes to a plus then left click to select and cell fills with solid blue color. Now do a Ctrl+V or right click Paste.

Alternatively to both of the above, move Title column in front of ID. Now ribbon Paste Append should work.

I tested this by copying your list from the question then pasting into my table.